# A telegram by Grothendieck to Serre

Tags: ho.history-overview, reference-request, soft-question

In an [opinion piece](http://www.ams.org/notices/201001/rtx100100005p.pdf) which appeared in the AMS Notices of January 2010, John Wermer tells us that he once heard about a seminar given by Grothendieck  which was described as "a telegram by Grothendieck to Serre". Is this anecdote recorded somewhere?

Comment: Try the Grothendieck Circle website of Leila Schneps. If everything fails, you could write and ask her.

Comment: To clarify: Mariano seems to be referring to a verbal communication, not a written letter.  Presumably, no one else in the audience could or was meant to understand.

Comment: Is this not a soft question?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think I heard Grothendieck's talk at the 1958 ICM described as a "a telegram by Grothendieck to Serre". But this would have been in a conversation (with neither Serre nor Grothendieck). I don't know whether anyone said it in a lecture, much less wrote it down.

MR0130879 (24 #A733) Grothendieck, Alexander The cohomology theory of abstract algebraic varieties. 1960 Proc. Internat. Congress Math. (Edinburgh, 1958) pp. 103--118 Cambridge Univ. Press, New York

Added: I don't know who first described Grothendieck's 1958 ICM talk as a "telegram to Serre", but I probably heard it from Lubin. Since Lubin and the article's author spent their careers at Brown, this fits.

Grothendieck's talk is available [here](http://www.math.jussieu.fr/~leila/grothendieckcircle/CohomologyVarieties.pdf). In it he lays out his plans for schemes and their cohomology. In 1958, not many people would have understood it.

Comment: Now it is also available here : http://www.mathunion.org/ICM/ICM1958/Main/icm1958.0103.0118.ocr.pdf

$$ $$

Answer (score 5):

You might want to know that a book exists, which consists of correspondences between Serre and Grothendieck. Its Google-Books link is [this](http://books.google.com/books?id=FBfygannPSUC&printsec=frontcover&source=gbs_navlinks_s#v=onepage&q=&f=false).